# File too big to open in Tinkercad. How can I shrink it?

Tags: 3d-models, 3d-design, stl, tinkercad

I need to shrink an STL file below the 25 MB threshold, so I can open it in TinkerCad. I don't care about quality, I just need it shrunk.

How can I do this?

[image: Screenshot of error]

Comment: We can't perform any services for you I'm afraid, so please don't ask. We can only suggest methods and solutions. I have appropriately amended the question for you. Also, please don't link links that require login as this could be construed as spam/phishing/etc.

Comment: a model that large will be a nightmare to edit using tinkercad....

Answer (score 4):

If you have 3D software like Blender you can import your model and use the decimate modifier to lower the number of vertices and then re-export.

Here is a link to how you can do this: [Simplify Geometry with the Decimate Modifier in Blender 2.9](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rHWCCYWhCMA).

Comment: Meshmixer will also decimate models, if one finds Blender to be overwhelming.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Microsoft 3D Builder](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/3d-builder/9WZDNCRFJ3T6) if you're under windows. It's a surprisingly powerful application that has basic but useful features. From there you can either resize the model to make it smaller or simplify it by lowering the triangle count.

Don't be fooled by the notion of it being a stock app, it's honestly the app I use the most when editing STLs.

Here's an example of an STL after being simplified alongside the original model:

[image: 3D Builder simplification]